# d3.js scatter plot connecting dots with line

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angular, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and i have been given a task to create a feet like in the image below. I have its X and Y coordinates and I am using scatter plot and line plot to create this but I am unable to draw a line on the boundary connecting the points. Here is the [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ni3mp4?file=src/app/scatter-plot/scatter-plot.component.ts)
[image]

This is the graph that i am able to make which doesnt look like the image above
[image]

Below is my code

```
export class ScatterPlotComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() data = [];
  private width = 350;
  private height = 500;
  private margin = 30;
  public svg;
  public svgInner;
  public yScale;
  public xScale;
  public xAxis;
  public yAxis;
  public tooltip;
  public lineGroup;
  constructor() {}

  public ngOnChanges(changes): void {
    if (changes.hasOwnProperty('data') && this.data) {
      console.log(this.data);
      this.data.forEach((element: { insoleX: number; insoleY: number }) => {
        element.insoleX = +element.insoleX.toFixed(2);
        element.insoleY = +element.insoleY.toFixed(2);
      });
      this.initializeChart();
    }
  }

  createDomain() {
    const minY = d3.min(
      this.data,
      (d: { insoleX: number; insoleY: number }) => {
        return d.insoleY;
      }
    );
    const maxY = d3.max(
      this.data,
      (d: { insoleX: number; insoleY: number }) => {
        return d.insoleY;
      }
    );
    const nonNegativeAxis = minY >= 0 && maxY >= 0;
    const positiveAndNegativeAxis = minY < 0 && maxY > 0;

    let yScaleDomain: any[], xScaleDomain;

    if (nonNegativeAxis) {
      yScaleDomain = [
        0,
        d3.max(this.data, (d: { insoleX: number; insoleY: number }) => {
          return d.insoleY;
        }),
      ];
    } else {
      yScaleDomain = d3.extent(
        this.data,
        (d: { insoleX: number; insoleY: number }) => {
          return d.insoleY;
        }
      );
    }

    xScaleDomain = d3.extent(
      this.data,
      function (d: { insoleX: number; insoleY: number }) {
        return d.insoleX;
      }
    );
    xScaleDomain[1] = xScaleDomain[1] + 2;
    return { xScaleDomain, yScaleDomain };
  }

  initializeChart() {
    const { xScaleDomain, yScaleDomain } = this.createDomain();

    this.svg = d3
      .select('#my_dataviz')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', this.width + this.margin + this.margin)
      .attr('height', this.height + this.margin + this.margin)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin + ',' + this.margin + ')');

    this.xScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain(xScaleDomain)
      .rangeRound([0, this.width - 2 * this.margin]);

    this.xAxis = this.svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.height + ')');

    this.yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([yScaleDomain[1] + 2, yScaleDomain[0]])
      .rangeRound([0, this.height - 2 * this.margin]);

    this.yAxis = this.svg.append('g').attr('id', 'y-axis');

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.xScale);
    this.xAxis.call(xAxis);
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(this.yScale);
    this.yAxis.call(yAxis);

    const line = d3
      .line()
      .x((d) => d[0])
      .y((d) => d[1])
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

    const points: [number, number][] = this.data.map((d) => [
      this.xScale(d.insoleX),
      this.yScale(d.insoleY),
    ]);

    this.svg
      .append('path')
      .datum(points)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke', '#69b3a2')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .attr(
        'd',
        d3
          .line()
          .x((d) => d[0])
          .y((d) => d[1])
      );
    // Add the points
    this.svg
      .append('g')
      .selectAll('dot')
      .data(this.data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'dot')
      .classed('filled', true)
      .attr('fill', '#83B9EE')
      .attr('data-xvalue', (d: { insoleX: any }) => d.insoleX)
      .attr('data-yvalue', (d: { insoleY: any }) => d.insoleY)
      .attr('cx', (d: { insoleX: any }) => this.xScale(d.insoleX))
      .attr('cy', (d: { insoleY: any }) => this.yScale(d.insoleY))
      .attr('r', 4);
  }
```

Is there any other way to do this ? Or how can I refractor this? Please help.

Comment: Your points are in a wrong order. You have to sort them to ensure the revious and the next points in the sequence are the closest to the current one

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I sorted the y-axis in ascending order, the graph improved but some points are still not forming a proper line
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y57hD.png

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I managed to replicate the code on stackblitz, can you please look at it?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ni3mp4?file=src/app/scatter-plot/scatter-plot.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modified **orderSequence** to move up/down instead of left/right. Does it help?

```
const orderSequence = seq => {
    let goUp = false;
    let input = [...seq];
  let output = [input.shift()];
  while(input.length > 0) {
    const last = output[output.length - 1];
    const points = [...input].filter(({y}) => 
        goUp ? y < last.y : y >= last.y);
    if (points.length === 0) {
        goUp = !goUp;
    } else {
      const closest = findClosestPoint(last, points);
      output.push(closest);
      const index = input.findIndex(p => 
        p.x === closest.x && p.y === closest.y);
      input.splice(index, 1);  
    }  
  }
```

Comment: It does help with the line but its still  pointing in the wrong direction
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdvWg.png

Comment: You can check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ni3mp4?file=src/app/scatter-plot/scatter-plot.component.ts

Comment: You can reverse the sequence by calling reverse(). Also, you can push the first item in the sequence to the tail to draw the closed path. Please mark and upvote the corrent answer it helps

Comment: I was able to draw the closed path but when i reverse the sequence with const ordered = orderSequence(randomPoints).reverse(), it still stays the same for some reason

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how the resulting order affects the whole plot. It seems to be the same regardless the starting point and direction

Comment: I think I get what you mean. Just invert the y coordinates of the resulting sequence seq = ordered.map(p => ({x: p.x, y: -p.y})); You don't need reverse(), is meaningless here. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230845/discussion-between-michael-rovinsky-and-maliha-khizer).

Answer (score 0):

The **orderSequence** routine is an example of how to order the sequence of points to form a loop.

The left sequence in the snippet is unordered and the right is an ordered one:

```js
let i;
const randomPoints = [];
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    const angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  const x = 100 + Math.sin(angle) * 50;
  const y = 75 + Math.cos(angle) * 50;
  randomPoints.push({x, y});
}

const distance = (from, to) => 
    Math.hypot(from.x - to.x, from.y - to.y);
  
const findClosestPoint = (point, seq) => 
    seq.reduce((closest, current) => 
        closest === null ? 
        current : 
        (distance(current, point) < distance(closest, point) ? 
        current : closest), 
      null);

const orderSequence = seq => {
    let goLeft = false;
    let input = [...seq];
  let output = [input.shift()];
  while(input.length > 0) {
    const last = output[output.length - 1];
    const points = [...input].filter(({x}) => 
        goLeft ? x < last.x : x >= last.x);
    if (points.length === 0) {
        goLeft = !goLeft;
    } else {
      const closest = findClosestPoint(last, points);
      output.push(closest);
      const index = input.findIndex(p => 
        p.x === closest.x && p.y === closest.y);
      input.splice(index, 1);  
    }  
  }
  return output;
}

const ordered = orderSequence(randomPoints);

const svg = d3.select('svg')

const drawSequence = (seq, container) => 
    seq.forEach(({x, y}, index) => {
        container.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', x).attr('cy', y)
      .attr('r', 3).style('fill', 'red');
    
  if (index > 0) {
    const prev = seq[index - 1];
    container.append('line')
        .attr('x1', prev.x).attr('y1', prev.y)
      .attr('x2', x).attr('y2', y)
      .style('stroke', 'blue');
  }  
});

const c1 = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
drawSequence(randomPoints, c1);

const c2 = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(200, 0)');
drawSequence(ordered, c2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="150">
  
</svg>
```

Comment: I suggest to modify the sorting routine and use up/down directions instead of left/right

Comment: This really worked for me, but at some points the lines do not sit correctly like in the image I attached. Is it possible that the incorrect points are generated? 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeFyM.png