# D3.js create an outline to the clipath shape

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, d3.js

I have created a foot and added color gradient as shown in the solution for the below questions.
[Add multi color gradient for different points in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67174318/add-multi-color-gradient-for-different-points-in-d3-js)
[d3.js scatter plot connecting dots with line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66970026/d3-js-scatter-plot-connecting-dots-with-line)
[image]

I have used clipath method to clip this foot. Now I want to set a black outline to this foot mask like in the picture below

[image]

Here is the [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ni3mp4?file=src/app/scatter-plot/scatter-plot.component.ts)

Comment: Outline for the external contour only or all the lines inside a foot?

Comment: outline for the external contour only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
this.svgInner
  .append("path") 
  .attr("d", line(ordered))
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", 1)
  .style("fill", "none");
```

After line **300** of **scatter-plot.component.ts** in your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jntg59?file=src/app/scatter-plot/scatter-plot.component.ts)

Comment: Can you also look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544157/generate-n-colors-between-two-colors

Comment: Yes, it's a known issue. Need help with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312494/convert-2d-shape-into-3d-in-d3-js-and-adjust-height-according-to-the-value-in-an

can you please check this question ?

Comment: @MalihaKhizer well, it's a tough one :) I think it will take some time, but I can try...

Comment: yes its quite tough, i tried with d3-3d but its not compatible with v6 version, take your time

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: Good morning :) Not yet. I tried to look for a library translating 3D bodies to 2D plane surface, did not find anything simple and usable wo work with SVG. There is also the 3D canvas, maybe it's something that can help...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/